# How to convert colnames into text/vectors based on the frequency?

Tags: r, text, dplyr, reshape

Assume I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c('A','B','C'),Var1=c(2,6,2),Var2=c(0,3,1),Var3 = c(2,0,3))
```

I want to convert my dataframe into something like this:

```
ID Variables
A  Var1 Var1 Var3 Var3
B  Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var2 Var2 Var2 
C  Var1 Var1 Var2 Var3 Var3 Var3
```

Generally, the `Variables` column is equal to `rep('Colnames Here','Frequency')`

Need help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(var, val, -ID) %>%
  filter(val != 0) %>%
  mutate(Variables = map2_chr(var, val, ~paste(rep(.x, .y), collapse = ' '))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(Variables = paste(Variables, collapse = ' '))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ID    Variables                                   
  <fct> <chr>                                       
1 A     Var1 Var1 Var3 Var3                         
2 B     Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var1 Var2 Var2 Var2
3 C     Var1 Var1 Var2 Var3 Var3 Var3
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your answer!